# Pgfplots domain

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have three columns of data and one which stops at a moment, but the other continues. But LaTeX creates the values as a constant, and I don't want them to appear, how to do?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
      \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12,width=1.\linewidth}
\begin{axis}[minor tick num=4,xlabel=Applied magnetic field $H(T)$,ylabel=Critical current value $I_c(A)$]
\addplot+[blue,mark=diamond] table [blue,mark=diamond,x=H, y=Ie]{IcH.csv};
\addplot+[red,mark=diamond] table [red,mark=diamond,x=H, y=It,domain=0:3.6]{IcH.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Curves of blabla.}
    \end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have your data, so I just made up some numbers which is nowhere near what you have, but it illustrates the point.

This answers is stolen from Dr. Manuel Kuehner's [pgfplots, plot options ignored when using “restrict expr to domain”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56053/89976).

**Output**
[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dataa.csv}
H,Ie,c,It
1,4,5,1
2,3,1,5
3,5,6,1
4,1,4,9
5,3,4,7
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=0.5]
      \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12,width=1.\linewidth%
      }
\begin{axis}[minor tick num=4,xlabel=Applied magnetic field $H(T)$,ylabel=Critical current value $I_c(A)$]
\addplot+[blue,mark=diamond] table [blue,mark=diamond,x=H, y=Ie,col sep=comma]{dataa.csv};
\addplot+[red,mark=diamond,
        restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{H}}{0:3}, 
        unbounded coords=discard,
        ]table [red,mark=diamond,x=H, y=It,,col sep=comma]{dataa.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```